# Conditional Order By query with current date

Tags: postgresql, date

I have products in Postgresql database table with these columns:

```
standard_price   -- Price of product
promo_price      -- Price of product in sale
promo_date_from  -- Sale is valid from
promo_date_to    -- Sale is valid to
```

The task is to order products by their current price. Current price is promo_price, when today is within promo_date_from and promo_date_to; otherwise current price is standard_price.

One possible solution is something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM products 
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN promo_date_from <= '2020-02-24'::date AND '2020-02-24'::date <= promo_date_to THEN
        promo_price 
    ELSE 
        standard_price 
    END;
```

However, this solution is quite slow and I don't know, how to speed it up? Is there any kind of index, which can be useful in this scenario or better approach like views, functions, ...?

The main problem is, I think, that query is not "static" - it depends on date parameter, which is part of query ('2020-02-24' in the example above).

Thank you for your help.

**Update:**

From comments bellow I get an idea, is it somehow possible to do something like this:

1. There will be index on `standard_price`, `promo_price`, `promo_date_from` and `promo_date_to`.
2. Using indices above these queries will be fast:

   query_promo = `SELECT *, promo_price AS current_price FROM products WHERE '2020-02-24'::date BETWEEN promo_date_from AND promo_date_to ORDER BY promo_price`

   and

   query_standard = `SELECT *, standard_price AS current_price FROM products WHERE NOT('2020-02-24'::date BETWEEN promo_date_from AND promo_date_to) ORDER BY standard_price`
3. Queries above give me two sorted sets with empty intersection, so using UNION ALL is safe. Now, the best optimization will be to union them using some kind of merge sort algoritm.

So, the question is, is there something in Postgresql, which can merge these two sorted sets into one set (by `current_price` column)? And finally after that apply limit/offset for pagination?

Comment: Creating indexes on the date fields will not help for this query. For every record the decision between the two prices must be made. I have tried your version and it was very fast for me. I've even tried to split up the query to two parts, the first part from the "THEN" , the second part from the "ELSE" and then combined them with UNION ALL, finally using them as subquery. In this case theoretically the indexes could be used but practically the optimizer decides not to use them. This is because using index is also work, it is only worth to use it when it helps you to avoid reading many rows.

Comment: Thank you for your help, which gives me an idea...

Comment: I am with quantummind here; the fastest approach for the DBMS to do this is a full table scan. An index doesn't help. If you need the current price very often, then you may consider running a script every morning that evaluates the current price per product and stores it in an additional column. (This is redundant of course, but sometimes we need such measures.) An alternative may be parallel processing via `set max_parallel_workers`: https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/02/21/parallel-queries-in-postgresql/)

Comment: Yes, you are right. As a backup solution I am considering daily script, which should be very fast (one update query). Redundant columns for optimizations is OK. Only disadvantage is (as I know), it must be implemented outside Postgresql. I prefer "Postgresql solution only", but as I said, this is good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION prices (d DATE DEFAULT now())
RETURNS TABLE (id int, name VARCHAR, price decimal(12,2)) AS $$
SELECT
  id,
  name,
  CASE WHEN $1 BETWEEN promo_date_from AND promo_date_to
    THEN promo_price
    ELSE standard_price
  END
  FROM your_table
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

The date defaults to current date or you can give the value date as a parameter:

```
select * from prices() order by price;
select * from prices('2020-02-02') order by price;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, your solution seems to be prettier for usage (much simpler select query). From the speed point of view, it seems to be quite a bit slower than solution with case statement directly written in order query.

Comment: How many rows does the table have? How much of them hit the date check? Are there many more fields and WHERE clauses? Looking at EXPLAIN ANALYZE, what seems to be the problem point? In case I want to generate some test data and make speed tests...

Comment: I tried to simplify my question to the core of problem, database structure is more complex. Table with prices and additional data (about has about 200k records. Where clause can be more complex (products must be published (needs join to check if product is published), from given category and its subcategories) plus limit+offset for pagination. Date check is in about 1% of records for now, but this can increase in the future (it is up to admin of our system). Explain says the highest cost is in sorting, everything other works perfectly. I need sorting to achive "sort products by price" filter.